# New file not appearing in Intellij project explorer

Tags: intellij-idea

After I add a file to Intellij from the project explorer (like new class or new package), I don't see it appear in the project files.
I tried to collapse and expand it, but still nothing.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Any exceptions in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)? Do you keep the project files on the local drive? Do you save it in OneDrive/Dropbox/other sync service location?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I don't see anything suspicious in idea.log. Files are saved on local drive

Comment: Please report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) and a video of the problem.